# Updating django version in virtaulenv but still showing old version

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

I am trying to upgrade my django version inside virtualenv and its showing that django is updated but its still not updated.

```
D:\testEnv>tan\Scripts\activate.bat
(tan) D:\testEnv>pip freeze
BeautifulSoup==3.2.1
Django==1.4.3
distribute==0.6.15
django-export-xls==0.1.1
jdcal==1.0
openpyxl==2.0.4
pypm==1.3.4
pythonselect==1.3
pywin32==214
virtualenv==1.6.1
wsgiref==0.1.2
xlwt==0.7.5

(tan) D:\testEnv>pip install Django --upgrade
Downloading/unpacking Django
  Downloading Django-1.7.1.tar.gz (7.5Mb): 7.5Mb downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package Django

    warning: no previously-included files matching '__pycache__' found under directory '*'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.py[co]' found under directory '*'
Installing collected packages: Django
  Found existing installation: Django 1.4.3
    Not uninstalling Django at c:\python27\lib\site-packages, outside environment D:\testEnv\tan
  Running setup.py install for Django

    warning: no previously-included files matching '__pycache__' found under directory '*'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.py[co]' found under directory '*'
    Installing django-admin-script.py script to D:\testEnv\tan\Scripts
    Installing django-admin.exe script to D:\testEnv\tan\Scripts
Successfully installed Django
Cleaning up...

(tan) D:\testEnv>pip freeze
BeautifulSoup==3.2.1
Django==1.4.3
distribute==0.6.15
django-export-xls==0.1.1
jdcal==1.0
openpyxl==2.0.4
pypm==1.3.4
pythonselect==1.3
pywin32==214
virtualenv==1.6.1
wsgiref==0.1.2
xlwt==0.7.5

(tan) D:\testEnv>python
ActivePython 2.7.2.5 (ActiveState Software Inc.) based on
Python 2.7.2 (default, Jun 24 2011, 12:21:10) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import django
>>> dir(django)
['VERSION', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', 'get_version']
>>> django.get_version
<function get_version at 0x022F7AB0>
>>> django.get_version()
'1.4.3'
>>>
```

As my django old verion is 1.4.1 after upgrading it should be 1.7.1 and its showing message **Successfully installed Django** but still showing old version of django.
So how should i update my django version here. Plus i need help to update django version 1.6.1 here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the key is in:

```
Not uninstalling Django at c:\python27\lib\site-packages, outside environment D:\testEnv\tan
```

You have a django installation outside your virtualenv and somehow it is ignoring the one you are installing and taking that one. Remove it and try again.

As a side note, i tried working with django/python in windows for a long time...then gave up begging windows to let me work and switched to another SO. If you want to stay in windows i advice you to at least use [vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/), will make your life easier in the long run.

Comment: That was very helpful but i'm not aware vagrant at all. If possible can provide me some link for help and it would be great if there is any example of django implementation on vagrant.

Comment: Try: https://github.com/torchbox/vagrant-django-template. Right after the clone go to your requirements.txt and change django to latest version. Remember to read vagrant's docs. Btw, fixed your issue right???

Comment: My issue is not fixed actually but you gave me other way for that and i feel that's even better as i come to know about Vagrants but still have to learn about it. Is it kind of virtual machine for a different os platform ?

Comment: Is a virtual machine for linux. You just create it, run your server from the machine (and install all the dependencies there) and test/upgrade your base code from windows.